# How do I add a ListTile to a list every time a button is pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

I am working on a navigation assistance application and one of the functions is to save a current location. I have tried implementing this by creating a list and adding the new location using the `listName.add()` command. The problem is that the list created doesn't add the coordinates, rather adds a null item. When I `print(position)` the console gives the coordinates but `Text(position.toString()),` returns null in the list. How do I change this?

````
  List<Text> savedPosition = [];

  
             ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.add_location),
                  title: Text('Save Current Location'),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      savedPosition.add(
                        Text(position.toString()),
                      );
                    });
                  },
                ),
                
                
         
                  
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text(
                            'Save Location',

                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              savedPosition.add(
                                Text(position.toString()),
                              );
                            });
                            print(savedPosition);
                            print(position);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(children: savedPosition),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}```
````

Comment: Wow, so much code to read for a simple state management question! Please, at least add comments at the exact places that are related to the question.

Comment: @rasuru I've tried to edit out the parts that don't seem very relevant. Please have a look.

Comment: You are adding a Text to your list its just that position is null. So you are effectively adding `Text('null')`.

Comment: @osodo sorry, maybe I am missing something, but I don't see (in previous edit too) any update of `position` field. It's just `null` at all times maybe you are forgetting to update it in your stream subscription?

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is as there's not enogh code to investigate. Basically, your `position` is `null` at the time when UI is building and it's not `null` at the time you print it to the console.